# Ask Google Music for tag suggestion with uploaded songs

Tags: google-play-music

I'm using Google Music Manager on Debian.

After uploading Metallica - St Anger Album (yes, I know), Google Music web app suggested me some tags.

It was all really good, it suggested a cover picture, the genre and year for the album. I clicked "Use suggestions".

I can't imagine why, but two of the 11 songs did not change the cover image. Following the general law of "Try Again" in computer science, I deleted the album and uploaded again.

Now Google doesn't make any suggestion for this album, and I'll have to download and set a cover picture manually.

Is there any way to ask directly for tag suggestion or trick Google to show them again?